# How this output is coming?

Tags: c

I can't understand this code.
please help me in explaining how this code works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
 clrscr();
 P
 getch();
}
```

[image: This is code]

[image: This is output]

Comment: Maybe `P` is a macro in `<conio.h>`?

Comment: no ,macro needs ; at end

Comment: No they don't, if the macro expansion contains the terminating `;`.

Comment: How can you make a macro and explain me

Comment: `P` is obviously a macro. But I don't believe it is standard for `conio.h`. Probably someone messed with it.

Comment: `#define P printf("ram\n");`

Comment: Your compiler should have an option to create/show pre-processor output. With an IDE you can probably hover over the `P` and choose "peek definition" or something similar.

Comment: actually my teacher show me this code and told me to explain how this is  working. then i try and add function in stdio.h and replace that function with a macro name P but it needs ;(semicolon) at the end of P

Comment: Have you noticed `;` in the end of the line @Someprogrammerdude have shown?

Comment: @Johnny Mopp  yes same thought but i can't find any in turbo c++

Comment: That's a pretty old compiler. Tell your instructor there are plenty of free _modern_ C compilers out there.

Comment: People have posted _pictures of text_ before on SO, and normally get flamed for it, but an actual photograph of your screen really takes the biscuit!  What does the first photo add that is not already in the posted code for example.

Comment: @Clifford I think the picture might be beneficial, as looking at the question without it I would say "I don't believe you, post a proof".

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes that's why i posted it

Comment: @EugeneSh. : But it proves nothing - we'd have to see a video to see that the output was a result of building and executing exactly that code. (Please _do not_ post a video!).

Comment: @Clifford Well, I am not talking about the case someone is lying, but just about the case where the code presented is not corresponding to the real one. We have had enough of these...

Comment: I have to see that myself. Please provide a reference to the source of the specific compiler you are using. Assuming it is free of course. Or at least a link to the supplier website, maybe some documetnation digging has an answer.

Comment: Tell Teacher you could not get past the obsolete `void main()`. Did your teacher really supply you a code named `NONAME00.CPP`? I think you or he must have pressed the `P` key by accident.

Comment: when my teacher run that program it runs smoothly and shows Ram on console but when i try afterward its showing me error "p is not declare"

Comment: That is nonsense: the program has no output except to clear the screen. `ram` can only be the echo of what was typed. There is no `P` macro in those library files, and no user edits library headers.

Comment: yes, but what about p .when my teacher ran that it was not showing error but when i tried its showing me a error p is not declare

Comment: I would like to ask your teacher few question...

Comment: @EugeneSh. you can tell me ,I will forward those question to my teacher

Comment: I afraid you will fail your course if you tell it to him :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. No ,he is very friendly in nature just tell me questions

Comment: The teacher does not have magic fingers. The code he showed you - was different.

Comment: So the photos _were_ misleading!  They are not photos of the output from your program but that of your teachers.  Was it perhaps a separate installation and PC?  Or perhaps there were local alternative versions of this headers in play.  It is easy to generate the behaviour observed, but little purpose other than to confuse and obfuscate - whay are we wasting time on this?

Comment: Another possibility is that the `P` macro was defined on the line immediately following `clrscr();` but after column 80 so not visible on the screen.  That would explain the otherwise unnecessary blank line not included in the posted code text, and the also otherwise unnecessary stdio.h.

Comment: @Clifford yes that might be possible ,nice approach thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll play this silly game.  Your teacher is having a joke with you.

By the magic of https://www.naclbox.com/gallery/turboc :

Consider:
[image]

Then note the hidden macro definition on line 6 (note the column number):
[image]

Voila!
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , i am searching for this answer for a long time ,I am very happy thanks